# What is the difference between an API and a POD?

Tags: cocoapods

We have an API vendor who develops APIs for our use. Recently they moved from APIs to building PODs.

What exactly is a POD ? How is it different from API ?

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think there's a standard/general/accepted/common definition for this. So it might be more specific to the technology you/they are using rather than a general thing?

Comment: This is most likely a cocoapod for cocoa dependency management, see https://cocoapods.org/